# Is it possible to encode DWARF debug information into wat (wasm textual format)?

Tags: debugging, webassembly, source-maps, dwarf

I'm developing a compiler that compiles to WebAssembly Text format (.wat) and want to include debug info. Is it feasible to include DWARF debug information within the .wat file, or is it more practical to generate source maps directly?